# Junit 5 testing toString()

Tags: java, junit, tostring

I recently started messing around with Junit, now i want to check if my method returns the expected String. Just dont know how to do it

Here's my test method;`

```
@Test
void toStringTest(){

    Voetbalclub schoonhoven = new Voetbalclub("Schoonhoven");
    String expected = "Schoonhoven 2 1 1 0 0";

    schoonhoven.verwerkResultaat('g');
    schoonhoven.verwerkResultaat('w');
    assertEquals(schoonhoven, expected.equals("Schoonhoven 2 1 1 0 0"));

    System.out.println(schoonhoven);


}`
```

Ps: I know that my code is checking if its in the same memory spot, which it obviously isnt.
Also tried .equals(),still got the same result though.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: if you want to provide more info, don't post it in a comment, edit your question and post it there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@Test
void toStringTest(){
    Voetbalclub schoonhoven = new Voetbalclub("Schoonhoven");
    String expected = "Schoonhoven 2 1 1 0 0";

    schoonhoven.verwerkResultaat('g');
    schoonhoven.verwerkResultaat('w');
    assertEquals(schoonhoven, expected.equals("Schoonhoven 2 1 1 0 0"));

    System.out.println(schoonhoven);
}
```

Honestly, this code doesn't really make much sense. What your code is actually checking, is whether your schoonhoven variable is equal to a boolean, which it obviously isn't.

```
@Test
void toStringTest(){
    Voetbalclub schoonhoven = new Voetbalclub("Schoonhoven");
    String expected = "Schoonhoven 2 1 1 0 0";

    schoonhoven.verwerkResultaat('g');
    schoonhoven.verwerkResultaat('w');
    assertEquals(expected, schoonhoven.toString());
}
```

This will verify whether the result of schoonhoven.toStrign() is equal to the expected String.

[Here](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertEquals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) you'll find more information. The parameters you pass are:

1. the expected object
2. the actual object

Comment: Of course `Voetbalclub.toString()` needs to be correctly implemented for this

Comment: @Lino indeed, but since it's a test on toString, I think we can assume it's implemented

Comment: @Stultuske Thanks for taking the time to answer my questions, i just started learning Java about 2 weeks ago. I'm getting better by the day, love the people arund here and the community MUCH apreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to see what you want to test exactly, but I will try to guess. `schoonhoven` is an Object in your code. As far as I can see it has a method named `verwerkResultaat(char param)`. In a meaningful test you would like to check if that method is working as expected. So if that method for instance returning something, of type `String` you could do something like this:

```
    Voetbalclub schoonhoven = new Voetbalclub("Schoonhoven");

    assertEquals(schoonhoven.verwerkResultaat('g'), "Schoonhoven 2 1 1 0 0");
    assertEquals(schoonhoven.verwerkResultaat('w'), [some other result of type String]);
```

Hope that helps. You could also share the implementation of your Class `Voetbalclub` so I could give you a working example.

Answer (score 1):

**Assert Equals**

If you want to test equality of two objects, you have the following methods

```
assertEquals(expected, actual)
```

In your case, it would be

```
assertEquals(expected, schoonhoven.toString());
```

Both components of `assertEquals()` should be same.
There are other types of `assert` which you can find [here](https://www.guru99.com/junit-assert.html)